# MPAndroid BarChart label count and ValueFormatter not working properly

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have an issue with the BarChart and labels. The labels count is not correct. Even if I put a value directly:

```
xAxis.setLabelCount(5,true);
```

but what I get is only 4 labels. When I put 6 it becomes 5. It seems there is a bug.

Also the last item of the labels ( I am using a simple ValueFormatter) does not appear. If the number of labels equals the number of bars it repeats the first one twice even though I use the

```
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

and the x values for each bar is `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

Can anyone help me please?

**Update**

Look the image 
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x59Q2.jpg)

Here I am using a list of entries and the label is the data of the entry.

You see there are only 3 labels while the size of entries list is 4. and the first item repeated twice.

I make sure about the entries and there values :

```
        Log.d(TAG, "Size of categories : " + categoriesEntries.size());

        for (BarEntry e :
                categoriesEntries) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getX() + " " +  e.getData().toString());
        }
```

The logcat output:

```
10-21 15:16:49.569 31194-31194/com.shamdroid.myfinancialassistant D/Statistics Activity: Size of categories : 4
10-21 15:16:49.569 31194-31194/com.shamdroid.myfinancialassistant D/Statistics Activity: 0.0 Study
10-21 15:16:49.569 31194-31194/com.shamdroid.myfinancialassistant D/Statistics Activity: 1.0 Home
10-21 15:16:49.569 31194-31194/com.shamdroid.myfinancialassistant D/Statistics Activity: 2.0 Car
10-21 15:16:49.569 31194-31194/com.shamdroid.myfinancialassistant D/Statistics Activity: 3.0 Schools
```

The ValueFormatter :

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                int i = (int) value;
                Log.d(TAG, value + "    " + i);

                return String.valueOf(categoriesEntries.get(i).getData());

            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please, can you show a working example to see what can exactly be the problem?

Comment: @error404 Thanks for replying. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

For others who have the same problem, I solve it by removing setLabelCount()